# SNMP: Why do I get two different memory values?

Tags: memory, snmp, cisco, oid

I'm trying to figure out how to extract CPU, memory, etc. from a Cisco device with SNMP.

On Cisco's website I found this OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6 (= ciscoMemoryPoolFree)
http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.109.1.1.1.1.6&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true

I found out it's a "scalar object" and I can read two values from it.
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6.1: 35619504
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6.2: 2516216

Why is there two different numbers for the free memory?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've been misinformed. According to this web page:

http://support.ipmonitor.com/tutorials/684f20eeb613444dae5518d6bdf6c766.aspx

There are two scalar variables.

1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6.1 = Available Free Processor Memory [bytes]

1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.48.1.1.1.6.2 = Available Free I/O Memory [bytes]

ciscoMemoryPoolFree is the "syntax" (type) of both of these variables, not the name of them. It's a Gauge32, which in practice, you can treat as an unsigned integer.